# Google Play Store not starting after latest updates

Tags: google-play-store, android-11

I have a Blackview A55 phone with Android 11 and after the latest updates the store won't start.

Comment: If you already rebooted and the problem persists you may try a reset.

Comment: Short of re-victimizing the victim with a factory reset, we may suggest just 'Disable' Google Play Store, to uninstall the updates back to factory supplied, getting the opportunity to start the app again, then Play Store will take the opportunity to update, possibly correctly, after.

Comment: Thanks.  This is why I feel like waiting a few days because I feel like someone could be working on this problem right now.

Comment: Restarting the phone fixed it.